# Compatibility of the Trust Flex Design Tablet with Ubuntu

Tags: hardware, compatibility, graphics-tablet

Can anyone give me feedback about the compatibility of the [Trust Flex Design Tablet](http://www.trust.com/products/product.aspx?artnr=16937) with Ubuntu?

I couldn't find much useful information on the Internet so far.
Especially, I wonder, whether the 1024 sensitivity-levels are working properly.

I consider buying such a panel.

Any positive and negative experiences and issues are welcome!

Comment: For the price of Trush graphics tablets you may consider the cheaper Wacom Bamboo line of tablets instead. The support for Wacom tablets in Ubuntu is great and don't require any batteries!

Comment: I haven't found any Wacom Bamboo Tablet, which is cheaper than the Trust Flex Design Tablet. The price for this Trust Tablet starts with 29.90 €.

Comment: I'm not saying Wacom tablets are cheaper - I meant the "cheaper [...] line" - compared to the Wacom Intuos line. Anyway, in my opinion you **really** want to spend that €20 more on the Wacom. Really. Just for the hardware already and battery savings. Really

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding and thank you for your recommendation and opinion!